# In Azure Logic Apps, is there a way to combine response bodies which makes access easy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

So I am working in Azure Logic Apps and using Azure Functions with an HTTP trigger. I am trying to combine the response of two different functions I am running and supply another function with the combined body. So here's the format:

Func1 returns a body --> Func2 returns a body --> Combine both bodies ---> Input to Func3.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone has to offer. I am kind of new to this, so I do not know if it can even be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Compose JSON actions ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#json-actions)) and the full [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) describe with great examples scenarios.

let's suppose this :

response func1:

`{ name:"toto"}`

response func2:

```
{ lastName:"toto" }
```

So with the combine actions you should be able easly  to do this

```
{
response1: #resp1,
response2: #resp1,
}
```

and like this you need to adapt your func3 to accept this and you will have the full objects.

Comment: What if I already have a JSON array as one of the bodies with about 20,000 objects in the array?

Comment: i updated my response so it's more detailled.